# property fset function not getting called

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't work out what I've started doing wrong here. I've always initialized managed class properties with `property( fget=fget, fset=fset )` and I have a memory that both my getters and my setters used to work in both Python 2 and 3. Now, using code practically straight out of [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties), I'm finding that my getters work, but my setter functions appear to be ignored in Python 2.x - assignment to the property just wipes out its propertyness and replaces it with a vanilla attribute.  All is well in Python 3.x, however.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class foo:
    def getcode( self ): return self.__code
    def setcode( self, value ): self.__code = value.upper()[ : 1 ]
    def delcode( self ): raise AttributeError( "cannot remove the 'code' property" )
    code = property( fget=getcode, fset=setcode, fdel=delcode, doc='A single upper-case character' )

    def __init__( self, code='A' ): self.setcode( code )

f = foo(); f.code = 'A'
print( f.code )         # expect 'A', get 'A'
f = foo(); f.code = 'bbb'
print( f.code )         # expect 'B' but python 2.7.10 prints 'bbb'
f = foo(); f.code = 5   # expect an exception but python 2.7.10 does not raise one 
print( f.code )
```

Comment: Your class doesn't inherit from `object`

Comment: `*`facepalm`*`.  Thank you. And that explains why it always used to work:  I used to know that that was crucial.   If you promote your comment to an answer I will feel honour-bound to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Python 2.x classes do not inherit from `object`, which makes the
distinction between *old style* classes and *new style* classes introduced
by Python >2.2.

`property()` is a succinct way of building a data descriptor that triggers function calls upon access to an attribute, however it fully works as
described in documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) for new-style classes only: class has
to inherit from `object`.